# ToolBar Gets Misaligned in Release Build

Tags: visual-c++, toolbar

I have added some ToolBars(CToolBar [FIXEDBMP]) and a AnimateControl(CAnimateCtrl [FIXEDBMP,FIXEDSIZE]) to a ReBar (CReBar). No Specific positioning is done for any of the Tool Bars or Animate Controls. Now The Animate Control gets MISALIGNED(Goes in the Top Left over the Menu Bar) ONLY in the Release Build, whereas in the debug build it is in the desired position(Top Right along with other ToolBars). I am not sure if there are any Issues with Release DLL or am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

One of the following:

- in Debug you have an ASSERT() that evaluates the result of a method call which modifies the state of the AnimateControl. On Release, that method call is not being evaluated.
- You have code that executes only on Debug through #ifdef
- A variable is either being explicitly initialized differently on Debug and Release, or you are using uninitialized variable in your code.

Without seeing the actual code it will be hard to tell more.